# Удалить видимость коммитов в ветке

Tags: git, github

В ветке react-basic находятся 2 коммита задач **add task4** и **fixed the function** с мастера. 
http://prntscr.com/hoa814
уже оформлен ПР. как удалить видимость этих коммитов с ветки react-basic?

Comment: Github не показывает в PR коммиты, которые уже есть в ветке, куда предлагается PR. Так что либо эти коммиты отличаются и/или в мастере их правда нет, либо у вас PR направлен не туда куда вы ожидаете.

Comment: спасибо, вопрос решен.

Comment: @Kylinko опубликуйте, пожалуйста, решение в виде ответа.